# Event firing one page affecting another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages, say **page1.jsp** and **page2.jsp** and a common javascript file **script.js**.

I have an onclick call in page1.jsp like this:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="onTab_ServiceTypes();">004</a></td>
```

and this method is in script.js defined as:

```
<script>
  function onTab_ServiceTypes() {

    // Here I want to hide a div of page2.jsp, like this
       $("#div_of_page2JSP").hide();
  } 
</script>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to see both pages at once? I guess that's not possible,meaning , once you change the URL path , your previous click event doesn't hold good, unless you use cookies/web storage

Comment: are these independent pages? or have you already loaded the content of page2.jsp into a DIV using ajax?

Comment: they are totally independent pages and no any ajax calls as well ...

Comment: if they are independent, suggestions made by vinodadhikary and Arun P Johny will work

Answer (score 3):

you can't do that if both pages are independent(page2 is loaded via a page reload).

What you can do is to store the clicked state using a cookie/web-storage(local storage/session storage) then when the second pages is loaded check the state of the stored value and then hide/show those elements.

Comment: ahh I can't do that???? really??? I dont wanna mess up with cookies stuff just for this issue. Is there any way I can do this, like using window.location or something like that?

Comment: @jeewan in that case, as vinod suggested you can pass a state variable to server and use it to determine the state of the elements

Comment: @jeewan if you use proper plugin working with cookies are not that difficult have a look at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Hi Arun, I understood his solution and I probably try all of your comments/answers but my question is, why this line of code does not work? $("#div_of_page2JSP").hide(); the id "div_of_page2JSP" is unique in my whole project, so why jQuery selector is not working here?

Comment: because jQuery works on the dom that is loaded in the browser, when you are trying to access the elements in page2 from page1 those elemets are not present in the dom structure thus jQuery cannot modify it

Comment: ahhh got it, so you mean in this code $("#div_of_page2JSP").hide(); , jQuery will look the id "div_of_page2JSP" in page1.jsp and not in page2.jsp right?

Comment: @jeewan given the case you have opened page1.jsp if of course you have some page3.jsp, which also references script.js it might as well look there, given you currently have loaded page3.jsp in your browser

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right this is not possible.  You won't be able to manipulate elements not within the current DOM with JavaScript.  You could probably pass a variable in your URL like `page2.jsp?hideDiv=true` (You would have a better name for this variable...) when you click the link and navigate to `page2.jsp` and hide `div` on page load.

Comment: Thanks Vinodadhikary, I have voted you up but I dont want to close the question for now.